# Targeting C++/CLI project to .Net 6.0 - Error : Project does not reference "native,Version=v0.0" framework

Tags: c++-cli, .net-6.0

Am upgrading my WPF project to .Net 6 which internally refers C++/CLI project. So am trying to upgrade my C++ project also to **.Net6.0.**

Changed the below properties in .vcxproj

```
<CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

While building the project, it fails with the below error.

**Your project does not reference "native,Version=v0.0" framework. Add a reference to "native,Version=v0.0" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.**

[image]

1. Anyone please guide me on - referring a C++ project (.Net Framework 4.6) in .Net 6.0
2. Do we need to upgrade c++ library to .Net 6.0 to consume it in .Net6.0 apps
3. How can we add reference to “native, Version0.0” in TargetFrameworks

Comment: The latest version of .NET framework is **4.8.1**.  The version you mentioned - **6.0** is a version of .NET core which is quite different.

Comment: This error message is produced by Nuget, tripped by the ".net6.0-windows" moniker to believe it can add the .net6 dependencies to the project.  Not possible, Nuget does not support C++/CLI projects and .NETCore build support is duct-tape.  Best way to do this is to use the "CLR Class Library (.NET)" project template to create a dummy project and compare the resulting .vcxproj file to your legacy project file to know what changes to make.  You should see Keyword=NetCoreCProj, TargetFramework=.net6.0, CLRSupport=NetCore, Reference elements removed.

Comment: @HansPassant i have removed the nuget pkg references. I have created a simple C# native library, which is added as a reference in C++/CLI library targetting .NetCore3.1. Now i have added this cli interop library in .Net6.0 console app.  Getting the below error while running. Build is succeeded for all 3 projects. System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'NetCLRClassLib, Version=1.0.8313.17779, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

When I made my project changes to get a C++/CLI-based assembly to build using .NET 6, I had the CLRSupport and TargetFramework changes like you show. But, I also had to change the `<ItemGroup>` containing the Reference elements to instead use a single `<FrameworkReference>` element. Note that my code called into WPF so there's a lot of those assemblies there.

Old:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

New:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```